# WebSphere MQ Transactional Log file system full

Tags: ibm-mq

Transactional log file system(/var/mqm/log) become full and i am getting MQRC 2102 resource problem with Queue Manager while attempting client connection to this queue manager. What course of action we can do to resolve this?

```
LogPrimaryFiles=2  
LogSecondaryFiles=8 
LogFilePages=16384 
LogType=CIRCULAR 
LogBufferPages=0 
LogPath=/var/mqm/log/QMGRA/ 
LogWriteIntegrity=TripleWrite
```

Is adding additional disk space to /var/mqm/log is the only solution?

I have few queues that were full,but queue storage file system were only 60% used.

Please give me some ideas on this.

Comment: Circular or linear logs?  Check the qm.ini file if you are not sure.

Comment: LogPrimaryFiles=2
 LogSecondaryFiles=8
 LogFilePages=16384
 LogType=CIRCULAR
 LogBufferPages=0
 LogPath=/var/mqm/log/QMGRA/
 LogWriteIntegrity=TripleWrite

Comment: In case you are wondering about the edits to your questions, "MQ" is a pretty generic term that could apply to many different vendor implementations. Even though your tag says WebSphere-MQ I generally try to disambiguate titles and often body references that refer to "MQ" when they are specific to a particular implementation.  Regarding removal of the signature, that's just a SO convention intended to make the site more like a reference and less like a forum.  See "Signatures" in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures That conventions does not apply to comments, however.  Cheers!

Comment: Sorry Rob.Going forward I will follow the conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log file pages are 4096 bytes each so a setting of `LogFilePages=16384` results in log files extents of 64MB each.  With a setting of `LogPrimaryFiles=2` and `LogSecondaryFiles=8` there can be up to 10 log files for a total of 640MB.  If the file system that the circular logs resides on is less than this amount, it may fill up.

The optimum solution here is to increase the size of the log file disk allocation to something a little larger than the log file extents require.  If that is not possible or you need a temporary fix then it is necessary to change the size of the log file requirement by reducing the number of extents and restarting the QMgr.  Note that you can adjust the number of log extents but not the size of the extents.  If it becomes necessary to change the `LogFilePages=16384` parameter then it is necessary to rebuild the QMgr.

The number and size of of extents represents the total amount of data that can be under syncpoint at once but 640MB is generous in most cases.  In terms of time, it also limits the longest possible duration of a unit of work on an active QMgr.  This is because an outstanding transaction will be rolled back if it happens that the head pointer in the log file ever overtakes the tail pointer.  For example, suppose a channel goes into retry.  This holds a batch of messages under syncpoint and holds that log extent active.  As applications and other channels perform their normal operations, additional transactions drive the head pointer forward.  Eventually all extents will be used, and although there may be very few outstanding transactions the oldest one will be rolled back to free up that extent and advance the tail pointer forward.   If the error log shows many transactions are rolled back to free log space then you really would need to allocate more space to the log file partition and bump the number of extents.